# Create custom faults in SOAP webservice

Tags: apex, api, soap-api, webservices, soap

I am building a new SOAP webservice in apex and I want to know how to throw custom soap faults. I created custom exceptions in apex and throwed it but the stack trace is also thrown along with the error message.

Below is the sample webservice

```
global without sharing class dummyClassforRecoRemoteCAT {
    
    WebService static List<WorkOrderObject> getWorkOrders(String GroupName) {
        
        if(GroupName == null || GroupName == ''){
            throw new SOAPException('Groups is Mandatory'); 
        }else{
            return new List<WorkOrderObject>();
        }
    }
    
    global class WorkOrderObject {
        
        WebService String manufacturer;
        WebService String model;
        WebService String serialNumber;         
        WebService String workOrderNumber;
        
        public WorkOrderObject(Case c) {
            manufacturer         = c.Asset__r.Manufacturer__c;
            model                = c.Asset__r.Product_Code__c;
            serialNumber         = c.Asset__r.Equip_S_N__c;
            workOrderNumber      = c.Work_Order_ID__c;
        }
    }
    
    global class SOAPException Extends Exception {}
}
```

SOAP Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dum="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/dummyClassforRecoRemoteCAT">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <dum:SessionHeader>
         <dum:sessionId>*****DUMMY_SESSION_ID*********</dum:sessionId>
      </dum:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <dum:getWorkOrders>
         <dum:GroupName></dum:GroupName>
      </dum:getWorkOrders>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SOAP Response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>dummyClassforRecoRemoteCAT.SOAPException: Groups is Mandatory

Class.dummyClassforRecoRemoteCAT: line 6, column 1</faultstring>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

here in the response the fault string says

```
<faultstring>dummyClassforRecoRemoteCAT.SOAPException: Groups is Mandatory Class.dummyClassforRecoRemoteCAT: line 6, column 1</faultstring>
```

But i want it to be something like the below ones without the stack trace.

```
<faultstring>Groups is Mandatory</faultstring>
```

or

```
<faultstring>dummyClassforRecoRemoteCAT.SOAPException: Groups is Mandatory</faultstring>
```

please let me know if there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a way to control this according to Salesforce https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000331375&type=1